# cannot GetTradeOffers from Steam APIs

Tags: api, steam

I have followed the API doc but my response is not as expected.

`https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1?key={key}&get_sent_offers=true&get_received_offers=true&get_descriptions=true&language=en&active_only=false&historical_only=false&time_historical_cutoff=0`

The response I got is :

```
{
  "response": {
    "next_cursor": 0
  }
}
```

Am I quoting the right values?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is right, but you don't have any trade offer, go to your Steam account

> inventory
>
> > tradeoffers

Make a new trade offer, then send a request to the api you should see the offer now!